# ClipBucket Database Still Loading

Tags: php, clipbucket

I am trying to setup ClipBucket on an Ubuntu server but when I click Check Connection for the database is still loading :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What php version are you using ?

I had the same issue, seems it needs php5.4 or php5.5 to work correctly, without fpm-php activated.

hope this helps